# TFS TeamBuildTypes Folder Missing

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2010

Using TFS 2010.  I have created a number of new Build Definitions.  I also created new folder within the TeamBuildTypes folder locally and checked into TFS.  I fired up a Build and see the TFS Workspace creates the folder (on TFS), but is missing the TeamBuildTypes folder.  This folder is not created.  I am not sure why.  Can anyone help me with this?  I am expecting to see all the Build Types folder (that the Build Definitions are pointing to) inside the TeamBuildTypes folder.  My build is failing because my Target file is attempting to access a file within the TeamBuildTypes folder.

Thanks so much...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new build in VS 2010, the entire build configuration is saved in the database, their is no configuration file created by default.  You can use .proj and .rsp files to configure your build still, but, you need to change your build to use the upgrade template for the build process file.  Then the build process parameters will require a configuration folder path (to point the .proj file).

If you don't change the configuration for your build (in VS 2010), the build types folder won't be created and the configuration files will not be copied to your build server.